# Inserting data in one table using HQL in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I was reading the Hibernate HQL tutorial and found that HQL doesn't support `INSERT INTO..VALUES..` but `INSERT INTO..SELECT..` i.e. HQL only support insert from another table.

Suppose I want to insert same values in one table and that data is not from any other table i.e. the values are not in any other table.Then how can I do that in HQL?

Also, would like to know the rational behind such restrictions in HQL?

Comment: Don't understand who downvoted this question? Whoever did, please let me know the reason so that I can take care in the future

Comment: i'm not downvoter, but i think you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to use hql to insert if the data is from another table.

Simply get a reference to your entity, get a hold of a Hibernate session, and call save().

According to http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html#d0e2116

**Pseudo-syntax for INSERT statements**

> INSERT INTO EntityName properties_list select_statement

**Only the INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... form is supported. You cannot specify explicit values to insert.**

Comment: I am asking how can i insert a data in a table in HQL.
Note : Data to be inserted is not from another table.

Comment: I added hibernate documentation for insert.

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate is an ORM framework (Object-Relational Mapping).

Its job is that you give objects (Entities) to it and he manages the storage (through `Session.save()`, IIRC).

So, you do not use the HQL to insert new records, but use the ORM methods.

And (this is a guess) on the other hand, since loading entities from a table, copying them to other entities and storing them one by one is slow, HQL provides a shortcut to the SQL in the DB just for that specific operation for performance purposes.

Comment: I know using session.save() i can do the same but just want to know  how can i insert data(not from any other table) to a table using HQL.

Comment: The provider of the framework says you can't do that. You know an alternative, and a rationale for it is given. Yet you just say you want to do it that way... at least, we are lucky that you are a programmer and not an airplane pilot. If you want to just use SQL, use SQL and not Hibernate.

Comment: I never said i want to do that way, i am just asking if we can do that or not..i hope you understand the difference..

Comment: The documentation (and your post) clearly says that you can't in HQL. Use an SQLQuery, or a direct SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `session.save(object)` to insert data into tables.