# HQL to insert data into database

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am trying to insert data into database with hql.
My code is

```
try {
         String hql = "insert into ErrorLog(className,method,lineNo,error) "
                       + "values(:cn,:me,:ln,:err)";

            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.setParameter("cn", className);
            query.setParameter("me", methodName);
            query.setParameter("ln", lineNo);
            query.setParameter("err", error);
            int res = query.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Not able to insert data");
        }
```

This is not able to insert data.

Comment: What exception are you receiving?

Comment: sql syntex error not able to insert data

Comment: Please post the stack trace !!

Comment: Dont use hql to insert .Use session.saveOrUpdate(Errorlog);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745041/inserting-data-in-one-table-using-hql-in-hibernate

Comment: Why you dont used `.save()` or .saveOrUpdate()` method to insert ? This is what Hibernate is for.

Comment: my method is getting values for className,method,lineNo,error so I would like to use insert query

Comment: Than create object of class `ErrorLog` set value of it and use `.save(ErrorLog)` function.

Answer (score 4):

HQL is not prominently gets use to insert values in table. You need to use Hibernate's  `save() , saveOrUpdate()` methods for that purpose.

**HQL only supports insert from another table.**

They have following syntax for that.

```
INSERT INTO EntityName properties_list select_statement.
```

They don't have anything to mere entering values. so following syntax is invalid

```
INSERT INTO EntityName properties_list values ( : inputvalues ).
```

You need to change your approach accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you insert record with Hibernate:

1. The ErrorLog must be an @Entity and the hibernate must be aware of this mapping.
2. It must have an @Id, possibly a surrogate key primary key
3. You map all fields

   - String className;
   - String method;
   - Long lineNo;
   - String error;
4. You create a new ErrorLog entity and then you can call:

   ErrorLog errorLog = new ErrorLog();
   errorLog.setClassName(className);
   ....
5. Then you need to instruct Hiberante that you want this transient Entity to be persisted, so you can choose any of the following:

   - session.persist(errorLog);
   - session.save(errorLog);

Answer (score -2):

use `save()` or `persist()` method, which is called by `Session` object. and pass the object of DTO class in these methods;