# How to insert value to table base on other table in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I want to insert value to one table base on value that I have on other table. 
For example we have 2 tables:

1. Users (columns: id, user_name, current_balance)
2. History (columns: id, user_id, balance)

So when inserting a record to History table I want to take the 'current_balance' from Users table and insert value and History table.

This is my insert statement code:

```
Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO History (user_id, balance) 
                                          VALUES (:userId, :balance)");
query.setParameter("userId", userIdValue);
query.setParameter("balance", balanceValue)     
query.executeUpdate();
```

What I need to change in order to take 'current_balance' from Users table in `Hibernate`? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested SELECT query should work fine:

```
Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO History (user_id, balance) 
                                          VALUES (:userId, (SELECT current_balance FROM Users WHERE id = :userId))");
query.setParameter("userId", userIdValue);
query.executeUpdate();
```

This is modified version of your example (SQL). You mention that you want to do this by HQL? If that's the case I'm not sure that's possible, because HQL supports only `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` not `INSERT INTO ... VALUES`, see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745041/inserting-data-in-one-table-using-hql-in-hibernate).