# What is the difference between Hibernate save and SQL insert?

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, hql

Normally I stored my objects in the DB by inserting or updating them via sql / hql statements.

```
query = session.createQuery("INSERT INTO Employee(firstName, lastName, salary)");
query.executeUpdate();
```

Recently I read about Hibernates `session.save()` method which takes a class and seems to automatically do the magic for inserting the class with it's attributes into the DB.

So I was wondering, what does "save" do?

Does it just generate an SQL statement for the user?

Or are there any advantages or disadvantages compared to the normal hqlQuery way?

Comment: Have a look at [Inserting data in one table using HQL in Hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745041/inserting-data-in-one-table-using-hql-in-hibernate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save:

Save method stores an object into the database. It will Persist the given transient instance, first assigning a generated identifier. It returns the id of the entity created.

As [`docs`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#save(java.lang.Object)) says,

> Persist the given transient instance, first assigning a generated
>   identifier. (Or using the current value of the identifier property if
>   the assigned generator is used.) This operation cascades to associated
>   instances if the association is mapped with cascade="save-update".

Also have a look at [What are the differences between the different saving methods in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161224/what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-saving-methods-in-hibernate)